# How to enable suidperl in Debian wheezy?

Tags: perl, debian, suid

I have a Perl script which is owned by root and have setuid.

In this script I am changing the owner of a file passed as argument.

But on running this script I am getting

```
chown: changing ownership of `file': Operation not permitted
```

Someone told me script with setuid run with suidperl by default if it is enable.

But I don't think so that is happening in my case.

Can anyone help me in this matter? I am using Debian wheezy. My Perl version is 5.14.2. I tried

```
apt-get install perl-suid
```

but it did not work.

```
apt-cache search perl
```

gave me no candidate related to suid in Perl.

This is my Perl program

```
#! /usr/bin/perl -T

use Cwd 'abs_path';

sub check_path {
  my $file = $_[0];

  $file = abs_path($file);
  if ($file =~ /^\/home\/abc\/dir1\//) {
    return 1;
  }
  else {
    return 0;
    print("You can only update permissions for files inside /home/abc/dir1/ directory\n");
  }
}

if (@ARGV == 1) {
  if (&check_path($ARGV[0]) == 1) {
    $ENV{PATH} = "/bin:/usr/bin";
    my $command = "chown abc:abc " . $ARGV[0];
    if ($command =~ /^(.*)$/) {
      $command = $1;
    }

    $result = `$command`;
  }
}
elsif ((@ARGV == 2) && ($ARGV[0] eq "-R")) {
  if (&check_path($ARGV[1]) == 1) {
    $ENV{PATH} = "/bin:/usr/bin";
    my $command = "chown -R abc:abc " . $ARGV[1];
    if ($command =~ /^(.*)$/) {
      $command = $1;
    }
    $result = `$command`;
  }
}
else {
  print("Sorry wrong syntax. Syntax: perl /home/abc/sbin/update_permission.pl [-R] file_path");
}
```

Comment: Please show your program.

Comment: @Borodin i have added my code

Comment: in this code my checking the absolute path of file if it containd /home/abc/dir1 then only i want to execute chown command(as security measure). Depending upon no of arguments it will execute chown or chown -R

Comment: There is no more suidperl, see also http://serverfault.com/questions/549770/debian-wheezy-and-suid-perl

Comment: @SteffenUllrich thanks for your comment. but do you have any solution for my problem ?

Comment: you might use sudo or a custom setuid wrapper. But I really would recommand that you do neither of this, because your script has at least one critical security problem (and various programming errors/problems). Just try to run it with $ARGV[0]='/home/abc/dir1/; rm -rf /'

Comment: @SteffenUllrich yes you are correct. but if i give only chown command to user abc in sudo file then it may work? or i will discard arguments with ';' in them

Comment: If you give the sudo rights for just the chown binary the user can chown everything on the file. I think you have to get much more experience with writing secure code (and this is not the place to get into all the details), but some basic advice: never use ` cmd ` and never use system($cmd) or open(..,$cmd) but always use system(@cmd), open(...,@cmd) to skip any shells in between. And, use strict and use warnings everywhere in perl. Using -T is a good start, but it does not help if you fail in verifying the user input (e.g. just doing .* is no verifying at all)

Comment: @SteffenUllrich "If you give the sudo rights for just the chown binary the user can chown everything on the file." i didn't get this point. I  mean i want abc to be the owner of file provided and owner can change anything.

Comment: but owner should not be able to do a chown abc:abc /

Comment: maybe it would be the best just to give the specific user sudo rights to execute '/usr/bin/chown /whatever/path' and '/usr/bin/chown -R /whatever/path' and skip this whole perl thing.

Answer (score -2):

It's probably too late for you, but I had the same problem and used the following simple C wrapper (shamelessly taken from http://www.blyberg.net/downloads/suid-wrapper.c):

```c
#include <unistd.h>
#include <errno.h>

main( int argc, char ** argv, char ** envp )
{
    if( setgid(getegid()) ) perror( "setgid" );
    if( setuid(geteuid()) ) perror( "setuid" );
    envp = 0; /* blocks IFS attack on non-bash shells */
    system( "/path/to/bash/script", argv, envp );
    perror( argv[0] );
    return errno;
}
```

Replace the path in the C code with the path to your script, compile with

`gcc -o suid-wrapper suid-wrapper.c`

and set the permissions with

`chmod 6755 suid-wrapper`

suidperl ist no longer an option, it has been removed without replacement in perl 5.12 (see perl5120delta, i.e. http://search.cpan.org/~shay/perl-5.20.2/pod/perl5120delta.pod).

Comment: This is wrong. You should not be calling `setgid`/`setuid`, as that will set the real GID/UID (which you probably don't want). Also, that's not how `system` works (it only takes one argument), you probably want `execve`/`execle`

Comment: I've made this solution work by including the argument inside the command using `asprintf(&command, "script.sh %s", argv[1]); ` but I know this is not secure. Can you please propose the best-practice way to do this? Thanks. @Timmermans @yadutaf

Comment: `system()` is [declared as `int system(const char *string);`](https://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#7.22.4.8)  This code is worse than wrong - it claims to block IFS attacks but does no such thing.