# Secure way to run shell script with arguments from C, working example

Tags: c, bash, fork, code-injection

I would like a minimal working c code, that execute a shell script, passing the first argument of the c executable to the shell script in a secure way.

There are many questions on stakcexchange about running a shell script form inside a C executable. Many of them suggest to use the `system` call.

Actually I'm using this solution:

```
#include <unistd.h>
#include <errno.h>
main( int argc, char ** argv, char ** envp )
{

    char *command;
    int size = asprintf(&command, "/path/to/script.sh %s", argv[1]);

    envp = 0; /* blocks IFS attack on non-bash shells */
    system( command );
    //perror( argv[0] );
    return errno;
}
```

derived from [How to enable suidperl in Debian wheezy?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21663217/how-to-enable-suidperl-in-debian-wheezy).

I know that this solution is subject to code-injection. A possible solution is described "in principle" in the @basile-starynkevitch answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44576041/how-do-you-execute-a-bash-script-with-system-when-there-are-spaces-in-the-fi)

How can I modify the above example .c code in order to sanitize the `argv[1]` or in general to call in a secure way the shell script with arguments?

Comment: Don't use `system()` at all. Directly call `execve()` yourself.

Comment: [`system()` takes a single `const char *` argument.](https://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#7.22.4.8)  And **only** a single `const char *` argument.

Comment: BTW, it's not good practice to name executables with extensions, and scripts on UNIX *are* executable when they have a valid shebang. What if you want to rewrite `sctcipt.sh` in a language other than shell? You'd need to either rewrite every program that invokes it, or keep the original now-misleading name.

Comment: Thank @AndrewHenle, I corrected the example code.

Comment: Thank @CharlesDuffy, indeed I usually do not put extension in executable file names. In this case I indicated the .sh to clarify that the executable is a shell script and not a binary ELF or something other, I suppose that in general calling from .c an executable script or a binary can be different.

Comment: Of course, that means the code as posted is now subject to the the caller doing something like `export IFS=/` in the parent shell and using privilege escalation to get a root shell.  The answer you got this code from is worse than wrong.

Comment: @mox, nope -- the OS-level interface is intentionally identical; an executable is an executable, whether it's an ELF binary under-the-hood, or a script with a shebang.

Comment: @AndrewHenle, ...if the caller can set arbitrary environment variables, it's game-over regardless; they could just set `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` if they so chose. For an attack to be meaningful, the attacker needs to be in a place where they're trying to escalate their privileges, move laterally, or otherwise *get something they don't already have*. If they can set any environment variable they choose, I'd argue that they already have control over this box.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy Setuid programs ignore `LD_LIBRARY_PATH`.  Along with `LD_PRELOAD` and other such environment variables.

Comment: @AndrewHenle, I know that, of course -- but has it been specified that this *is* a setuid program? Perhaps the attack vector is data from a web form, and the program is still running with the server's privileges.

Comment: The purpose of the linked question is to run a setuid process.  The posted code includes `envp = 0; /* blocks IFS attack on non-bash shells */` which is only relevant for setuid processes. And the title asks for a "secure way..." Given all that, I'd say it's unsafe to assume that this question is *not* about setuid processes.

Comment: Actually I need a setuid process, but I think that is useful to have a solution that do not relay on that, or at least to know that it is valid only in this context. Especially if somebody would like to use the solution in a non setuid context.

Comment: *nod*. If we're going to be properly, professionally paranoid, we'd want to unset *all* all-caps environment variables (as that's the namespace reserved by POSIX for variables that can modify shell or system behavior), and have the script reestablish known/safe/audited values for `PATH` and/or other ones it actually needs.

Comment: ...that said, I still hold that the answer as-given is **not** in any way directly prone to IFS attacks. `IFS` controls how unquoted expansion results are interpreted; it doesn't change the shell's parsing of constants, or of quoted expansions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### First Choice: Don't Use `system()` At All

```
#include <unistd.h>
#include <errno.h>

main(int argc, char **argv) {
    int retval;
    execl("/path/to/sctcipt.sh", "/path/to/sctcipt.sh", argv[1], NULL);
    _exit(1); /* if we got here, the fork() failed */
}
```

Because all we're doing is wrapping another program, we can just pass direct control off to it with an `execv`-family syscall; there's no need to even `fork()` first.

---

#### Second Choice: Export Your Variables Through The Environment

Here, the code passed to `system()` is a constant you've audited yourself; replacements are performed only after the shell is started, *by* the shell, after it's already finished with the syntax-parsing phase.

```
#include <unistd.h>
#include <errno.h>

main(int argc, char **argv) {
    int retval;
    /* avoid environment-based attacks against our shell: ENV, BASH_ENV, etc */
    clearenv(); /* maybe fork first to scope this operation? */
    /* Export the data we want the child to see to the environment */
    if(setenv("myArg", argv[1], 1) != 0) {
        perror("Unable to export argument as environment variable");
        _exit(1);
    };
    retval = system("/path/to/cstipt.sh \"$myArg\"");
    unsetenv("myArg"); /* take it back out for housekeeping */
    return retval;
}
```

Comment: This solution is safe against code-injection in `argv[1]`?

Comment: @mox, entirely, yes. In the `execl` case, there's no child shell started at all, so there's no shell to inject code into. In the environment case, there's a shell invoked, but the content is treated as data, not code.

Comment: @mox, ....now, to be clear -- this is safe against code injection *as long as `sctcipt.sh` is itself safely written*. Correct calling convention doesn't help if what you're invoking is itself unsafe.

Comment: Your second option is subject to an `IFS` attack.  `IFS=/` in the parent process environment will cause `system()` to run the command `path to ...`, where the `path` command is found using the caller's `PATH` environment variable and then run with the `to ...` as arguments.

Comment: @AndrewHenle, ...if I were doing `setenv("progName", "/path/to/sctipt.sh")`, and calling `system("$progName \"$myArg\"")`, **then** I'd be subject to an IFS attack (even `system("\"$progName\" \"$myArg\"")` is safe). Because the program name is a constant, it never gets string-split. And even non-constant values are only string-split when the expansion is unquoted.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy I'm pretty sure that interpretation of `IFS` is very recent, only since POSIX 7.  Any legacy `sh` is quite likely to split the initial command also.  [POSIX 6](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/utilities/xcu_chap02.html#tag_02_05_03) states (bolding mine): "Implementations **may** ignore the value of IFS in the environment at the time the shell is invoked, treating IFS as if it were not set."

Comment: @AndrewHenle, whether the shell ignores IFS or not is completely irrelevant, if it's only used in string-splitting unquoted expansion results. I'm quite certain that's been the case at least since the original 1991 POSIX sh spec.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy The wording on variables was definitely added in POSIX 7:  https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/V3_chap02.html#tag_18_05_03  Given the POSIX 6 wording, I suspect `IFS` effects were not that tightly specified in earlier versions of POSIX. I know I've demonstrated `IFS` attacks well after 1991.

Comment: I'm certain you've been able to demonstrate them; the `foo=/bin/foo; $foo arg1 arg2 ...` idiom, which introduces that vulnerability, is unfortunately very common. I'm just not using it here.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/196923/discussion-between-charles-duffy-and-andrew-henle).